# How to Marshall and Unmarshall more then one POJO class using JAXB

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, xml-parsing, jaxb

I working convert java object to xml and xml to object by using JAXB.
But i got JAXBException, how can i solve it?

MainPojo:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "PCM")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class MBCASAAccountDetailsData {

@XmlElementWrapper(name = "SvcRq")
private ArrayList<MBCASAAccountData> casaAccountData;

@XmlElementWrapper(name = "BalInqRq")
@XmlElement(name = "DepAcctId")
private ArrayList<MBTestAccountData> accountData;

public MBCASAAccountDetailsData(){

}


public ArrayList<MBCASAAccountData> getCasaAccountData() {
    return casaAccountData;
}

public void setCasaAccountData(ArrayList<MBCASAAccountData> casaAccountData) {
    this.casaAccountData = casaAccountData;
}


public ArrayList<MBTestAccountData> getAccountData() {
    return accountData;
}

public void setAccountData(ArrayList<MBTestAccountData> accountData) {
    this.accountData = accountData;
}
}
```

SubPojo:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(namespace = "mbank.product.account.data.MBCASAAccountDetailsData")
public class MBCASAAccountData {

@XmlElement(name = "ChannelId")
private String channelId;
@XmlElement(name = "SvcCode")
private String serviceCode;
@XmlElement(name = "SvcRqId")
private String serviceReqId;
@XmlElement(name = "Timestamp")
private String timeStamp;
@XmlElement(name = "TimeoutPeriod")
private int timeOutPeriod;

public MBCASAAccountData(){

}
public MBCASAAccountData(String channelId,String serviceCode,String serviceReqId,String timeStamp,int timeOutPeriod){
    super();
    this.channelId = channelId;
    this.serviceCode = serviceCode;
    this.serviceReqId = serviceReqId;
    this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
    this.timeOutPeriod = timeOutPeriod;
}


public String getChannelId() {
    return channelId;
}
public void setChannelId(String channelId) {
    this.channelId = channelId;
}


public String getServiceCode() {
    return serviceCode;
}
public void setServiceCode(String serviceCode) {
    this.serviceCode = serviceCode;
}


public String getServiceReqId() {
    return serviceReqId;
}
public void setServiceReqId(String serviceReqId) {
    this.serviceReqId = serviceReqId;
}


public String getTimeStamp() {
    return timeStamp;
}
public void setTimeStamp(String timeStamp) {
    this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
}


public int getTimeOutPeriod() {
    return timeOutPeriod;
}
public void setTimeOutPeriod(int timeOutPeriod) {
    this.timeOutPeriod = timeOutPeriod;
}
}
```

Second SubPojo:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(namespace = "mbank.product.account.data.MBCASAAccountDetailsData")
public class MBTestAccountData extends BusinessData {

@XmlElement(name = "AcctId")
private String accountNo;
@XmlElement(name = "AcctType")
private String accountType;

public static final String ACCOUNT_NUMBER = "accountNo";
public static final String ACCOUNT_TYPE = "accountType";

public MBTestAccountData(){

}
public MBTestAccountData(String accountNo,String accountType){
    super();
    this.accountNo = accountNo;
    this.accountType = accountType;
}


public String getAccountNo() {
    return this.accountNo;
}

public void setAccountNo(String accountNo) {
    set(ACCOUNT_NUMBER, accountNo);
    this.accountNo = accountNo;
}


public String getAccountType() {
    return this.accountType;
}

public void setAccountType(String accountType) {
    set(ACCOUNT_TYPE, accountType);
    this.accountType = accountType;
}
}
```

Main Class (TestClass):

```
String customerID = "56789";

        MBCASAAccountData casaAccountData = new MBCASAAccountData(CommonConstants.CHANNEL_ID, AccountSummaryConstants.CASA_DETAILS_SERVICE_ID, MBankUtill.getServiceId(customerID.length())+customerID,DateUtil.getStringFromDate(new Date(), AccountSummaryConstants.DATE_FORMAT),AccountSummaryConstants.TIMEOUT_PERIOD_IN_SECONDS);
ArrayList<MBCASAAccountData> test = new ArrayList<MBCASAAccountData>();
        test.add(casaAccountData);

        MBTestAccountData accountData = new MBTestAccountData("123456","26");
ArrayList<MBTestAccountData> test2 = new ArrayList<MBTestAccountData>();
        test2.add(accountData);

        MBCASAAccountDetailsData accountDetailsData = new MBCASAAccountDetailsData();
        accountDetailsData.setCasaAccountData(test);
        accountDetailsData.setAccountData(test2);

        try {
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(mbank.product.account.data.MBCASAAccountDetailsData.class);
            Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            marshaller.marshal(jaxbContext, System.out);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Exception:

```
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl nor any of its super class is known to this context.
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getBeanInfo(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.marshal(Unknown Source)
at mbank.accounts.testng.test.TestClass.main(TestClass.java:282)
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<PCM>

<SvcRq>

<ChannelId>*RIB1</ChannelId>

<SvcCode>AS_CSDETINQ_N</SvcCode>

<SvcRqId>20140311522xxx</SvcRqId>

<Timestamp>110314022518</Timestamp>

<TimeoutPeriod>45</TimeoutPeriod>

</SvcRq>

<BalInqRq>

<DepAcctId>

  <AcctId>003573081xxx</AcctId>

  <AcctType>26</AcctType>

</DepAcctId>

</BalInqRq>

</PCM>
```

Hi Guys, i need above output format. what can i do?
Please help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: can you please mention in your code where exactly the error is being thrown?

Answer (score 0):

Two hints:

```
JAXBContext.newInstance(MBCASAAccountDetailsData.class,
    MBCASAAccountDetailsData.class)
```

...

```
marshaller.marshal(casaAccountData, System.out);
```